# Reg expression to include intranet sites that dont end in .com / .net / etc

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I'm using the regexlib to come up with a regular expression to get a url out of a string.

So far I have the following:

```
    message = Regex.Replace(message, @"((http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+
([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?)", "<a target='_blank' 
href='$1'>$1</a>");
```

This seems to be pretty accurate but fails on two things:

1. I can't get it to recognize a url if its of the form `www.yahoo.com`
2. I can't get it to work for intranet sites so something like `http://mysite/Views/Issues/ListView.aspx` doesnt link :(

I despise regular expressions and could really use some help.

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/dperini/729294) has a regular expression, that, as elaborated [here](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex) covers basically all the cases.

Comment: @Cu3PO42 - I cannot seem to get that to work, could you every string text I've tried comes back with no url form for me.

Comment: since I can't see precisely how it is in your code, I can't really say something about that. I have used it successefully, but it doesn't really matter, since you already found something that works for you, does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

EDIT:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"(\b(?:(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|www\.|ftp\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$]|((?:mailto:)?[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6})\b)|""(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|www\.|ftp\.)[^""\r\n]+""|'(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|www\.|ftp\.)[^'\r\n]+')", "$1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Comment: Can you put this in the form of the returned result in c#, like this: `data = Regex.Replace(data, @"((http|ftp|https):\/\/|[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]?)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@‌​?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?)"` not sure how your solution would be taken into this.